# I need to use graphs in C++/C#. Is there any built-in C++/C# library which I can use?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, c++11

I want to use a graph in C++, so that I can use it for storing cities and distances between them, and then try some path finding algorithms on it. Is there any built-in library, etc. which I can include in my project?

Like #include<vector>, etc. If not, kindly tell me same for C#.

Comment: [BGL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, **library** or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The GDI library is built in to Windows. It is more than adequate if you are drawing some dots and lines.

Comment: I am not drawing dots and lines, I want to use it as a simple data structure to store nodes. I am making a console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do path-finding you just need some special forms of trees. Most of them are well described when you look at path-finding algorithms. As an example, you can use a [priority queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/) which is suitable for storing the successors at the top of your tree (fast access).

Concrete implementations I can suggest are A*:

You can build your own heuristic method, which means that you can put in your own logic for travelling.

One implementation of it is *[a-star-algorithm-implementation](http://code.google.com/p/a-star-algorithm-implementation/downloads/list)*.

Comment: I was also thinking that maybe I can use priority queue and some other arrays etc and there would be no need for graph?

Comment: As long as you don't want to visualize your graph, the priority queue structure is enough + some sort of list / array data-structures. It depends as well, how much data you will have and how your heuristic is (Overdetermined / Underdetermined). 

If you need sophisticated solutions, the boost library is very suitable, as it delivers data-structures and as well complete path-finding algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html)?

Boost usually provides very good libraries for data structures and algorithms.